# Prometheus & Grafana: templating and "bool" modifier

Tags: grafana, prometheus

I am building Grafana (4.1.1) graphs with a Prometheus (1.1.2) backend, and am trying to use Templates to select/deselect certain sub-sets of metrics on a dashboard. I have a template variable called "$POP" which describes my city locations, and a template variable called "$Resolver" which describes the type of resolver I am using ("unbound" or "pdns" are the possible string results.)

I have these two metrics like this that work quite well currently selecting on the various values in $POP:

```
irate(dnsdist_recursor_main_servers_unbound_drops{env="prod",loc=~"$POP"}[1m]) > 0
irate(dnsdist_recursor_main_servers_pdns_drops{env="prod",loc=~"$POP"}[1m]) > 0
```

Putting aside for the moment that instead of labels the selection criteria are embedded in the metric name (I know it's not ideal but this is just an example of larger problem sets so please do not suggest how I can use labels) I would like the following results:

When (~"$Resolver" == "unbound") I would like to show the first metric (dnsdist_recursor_main_servers_unbound_drops) and when (~"$Resolver" == "pdns") I would like to show the second one (dnsdist_recursor_main_servers_pdns_drops) and when both are selected I'd like to show both metric set data. Basically, I hope to have an on/off visibility trigger for a metric that is keyed to my $Resolver template value.

How do I create a boolean such that the metric is shown or not shown based on the setting of the string value in the templated setting of $Resolver?  The trick here is that the selection criteria is in the metric name, not a label, which is really stumping me.  I tried "bool" modifiers but was never able to get anything to work on string equality tests. I'm sure it's just a syntax issue but examples are thin on the ground.

Answer (score 0):

What you can take advantage of here is that there's no uniqueness restriction on label selectors, so you can do `{resolver="$resolver",resolver="unbound"}`

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand this method. Are you suggesting to add it in as a label on the selection?  If so, this doesn't work as I would expect (correcting for capitalization):  sum(irate(dnsdist_recursor_main_servers_unbound_drops{env="prod",loc=~"$POP",resolver="$Resolver",resolver="unbound"}[1m]) > 0)